# Myths and conventional WhizDumb of the internet

Tags: opening, learning, training, study

What is good advice and what were myths and whizdumb of the internet that kept you from improving as much/fast as you could have?

Play more games?
NO!  Focused training helps more than playing random games.
Perfect practice makes perfect not making unpunished mistakes against other weak players.

Studying more openings?
NO.
You need to focus on one opening for white and black.  And MASTER them.  Learning lots of openings gives you more openings with less ability in each of them.  END GAMES will help more than learning more openings.  And tactics are also needed to help play middle games better when using a clock.

Comment: I think a lot it will come down to personal experience, since different learning strategies work for different people.

Comment: The details may differ but having taught at the uni I suspect that the general approach to learning would be the same for almost everybody.

Comment: I'm not understanding what the question is.  Can you clarify?  Are you asking what good and bad advice I have received when learning chess?

Comment: @yobamamama If you teach at a university I hope someone will have pointed out to you that different people do indeed have different learning styles...

Comment: I know that quite well.  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: If you want to answer your own question, please do so by writing a separate answer to it. Writing an answer to your question in the question block is just you lecturing.

Comment: Wish I could but some schmuck closed the question claiming it is opinion based when something like 85% of the questions here are really opinion based.

Comment: It was probably closed because you wrote an answer to the question (in the question itself) with a very opinionated tone. It's best to state your question objectively, and then write whatever answer you want separately in the answer section.

Comment: Also, you've used words like "coward" and "schmuck" for having your questions/answers downvoted or closed. This isn't constructive; if you think carefully about what you post and write objectively good answers, you won't get downvoted as much.

Comment: I write good answers.  But there are several cowards and bulliies, and yes I know that is redundant making a concerted effort to downvote everything I post.  Comments appear to be the only thing safe from them.

Comment: @yobamamama This site has certain standards for questions and answers. If you don't write constructive things, you'll be downvoted. In the comments you aren't expected to meet any standard of quality, which is why they're exempt from as much scrutinization. And Chess Stack Exchange isn't nearly as strict as a community like Stack Overflow. People aren't downvoting your answers for no reason, considering it costs the person 1 rep to do so.

Comment: My comments are as constructive as any other.  The problem is that I use logic and some snowflakes use emotion and feelings instead.

Answer (score 5):

I think that the biggest myth about chess is the one that you actually pointed out in your question. I am talking about the one about learning openings before learning endgames. I am a strong believer that endgames contribute much to your play than openings and openings. As the great chess player Capablanca pointed out that Endgames can be studied independently while Openings and the Middlegame must be studied with the knowledge of a possible ending.